# Spotfire: Show and calculate difference of two values from selected dates in the plot

Tags: spotfire

I am showing a data of pressure in a graph by date which can be selected from the filter (days, months, years).

I would like to calculate the difference between the two data extrema in the plot `[last Value - first Value]` (when user changes a filter I show the new calculation as the graph will change)

```
PropertyName    AverageReading  Date
LevelPressure   1               1/1/2018
LevelPressure   5               1/3/2018
LevelPressure   24              1/2/2018
LevelPressure   4               1/5/2018
LevelPressure   3               2/2/2018
LevelPressure   2               2/3/2018
LevelPressure   1               2/4/2018
LevelPressure   77              2/1/2018
LevelPressure   33              2/2/2018
```

Here is my custom expression but it's not working properly (date is X axis values, level pressure Y axis):

```
Abs(if([Property Name]="LevelPressure",[Average Reading]))
    - sum(if([Property Name]="LevelPressure",[Average Reading]))
    over (PreviousPeriod([Date]))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are inserting a calculated column, it will always take into account the entire data set.  It will not take filtering into account.  You can create a calculated value and apply data limiting or filtering OR write an expression on the axis of a visualization.  Based on the expression you gave, it seems like  you are inserting a calculated column.  This will not work.

Comment: thanks Julie - yes am trying to created calculate column here but always taking entire data. but how can I add this expression on the axis itself?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that may or may not work for your use case.  Your explanation did not specify what type of visualization you are working with.  I assumed a scatter plot.  This solution will work with any visualization type.

Go to Properties > Lines and Curves > Add a Horizontal Line configured with a custom expression > Abs(Max([Y]) - Min([Y])).  This will put a line on the chart that is absolute value of the max and min average reading (average reading is your y axis value).  It will update with filtering.